# Al llenar una lista me lanza una exepción de "referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto"

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Estoy recuperando ciertos datos de una tabla de mi db en formato de lista, lleno mi lista en un ciclo `for` pero al momento de la primera iteración me envia una excepcion del tipo

> Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto.
>   Descripción: Excepción no controlada al ejecutar la solicitud Web actual. Revise el seguimiento de la pila para obtener más información acerca del error y dónde se originó en el código. 
>   Detalles de la excepción: System.NullReferenceException: Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto.

Tengo lo siguiente en mi código:

Controlador:

```
public class MiController : Controller
{
    private Data _Data;

    public MiController()
    {
        _Data = new Data();
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Region = _Data.GetRegion();
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(Region model)
    {
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

Clases:

```
public class Region
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string NombreRegion { get; set; }

    public List<Region> Regiones { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    private Region _Region;

    public Data()
    {
        _Region = new Region();
    }

    public List<Region> GetRegion()
    {
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(DetamaticAPI.DataBase.Connection.ConnString))
            {
                string SQL = string.Empty;

                SQL += "SELECT id, Region";
                SQL += " FROM Region";

                try
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(SQL, conn);
                    SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
                    DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
                    sqlDataAdapter.Fill(dataset, "Region");
                    conn.Close();

                    for (int i = 0; i < dataset.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        _Region.Regiones.Add(new Region()
                        {
                            Id= Convert.ToInt32(dataset.Tables[0].Rows[i]["id"].ToString()),
                            NombreRegion= dataset.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Region"].ToString()
                        });
                    }

                    return _Region.Regiones;
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {

                    throw;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

No se donde esta el problema que me esta indicando que existe un objeto con valor `null` alguien me puede ayudar para poder detectar en que me estoy equivocando?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probablemente te falta inicializar `Regiones`. Añádelo en el constructor de `Data`:

```
public Data()
{
    _Region = new Region();
    _Region.Regiones= new List<Region>();
}
```